# Exposing a library via zeromq

Tags: libraries, zeromq, distributed-computing

I am wanting to know what would be the best way to expose a library via zeromq. Say, I install a machine learning library (mll) on one machine, and I have a zeromq broker running on another. Now, if I have a zeromq client which needs to call functions within the mll, how can it do so via the broker.

I am wanting to know the steps I will need to take to make this work for libraries in a generic way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have a "listener" that picks up data from ZMQ and feeds it to your machine-learning backend code, then transmits the results back to the requestor.

There are a lot of design choices to be made, such as what format to use to serialize data between client and server (JSON? YAML? Pickle? Thrift? ...) , and how to encode requests and request options. But all things considered, this is a pretty straightforward ZMQ usage.

The problem comes when you want a more feature-rich, complete, robust, etc. design--things like multi-threaded or multi-process servers, multi-machine scalability, secure user / request authentication and authorization, job reporting and dashboard, or job checkpointing. All those "extras" are common "network job scheduler" or "(enterprise) message broker" functions that tend to come out-of-the-box with packages like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org).

If you don't want to go the full "message broker middleware" route, you might start by examining others' designs for lightweight ZMQ-based job brokers, such as [this one from Jeff Knupp](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/02/11/a-celerylike-python-task-queue-in-55-lines-of-code/).